# Display Block and Display None with Option Value

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm trying to create a toggle that will `display:block` and `display:none` for different blocks of code similar to the code box at [lob.com](https://www.lob.com/) beside "
An intuitive RESTful API".

I have been trying to get this to work based of this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaVBZ/1/) but I can't get it to work but I'm not sure if this code is what I need to achieve what's done at lob.com

```
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
    <option value="1">Jay</option>
    <option value="4">Sam</option>
    <option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
</select>
<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
    admin selected
```

JavaScript:

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
        if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Ultimately it will need to be able to toggle between the two drop downs like on lob.com  so there would be 8 sets of divs if there were 4 options on the left and then 2 on the right.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to learn how to do this as I'm not sure if I should be using JQuery or not. Basically I'd like to know exactly how lob.com did it so I can go down the right road!

Thanks if anyone can point me.

Comment: What is not working? The example is a little vague to me. Will this work for you?: `admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = (nameSelect && admOptionValue == nameSelect.value)?"block":"none";`

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood what you want, and where in that site should i be looking at? Right next where it says "An intuitive RESTful API" or where? is that what you want?

Comment: Yes Zarich that's what I'm trying to recreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website lob.com is build up with alot of `pre`'s inside a container. Start with the HTML:

```
<pre class="jayOption prettyprint" style="display: none;"><code>Jay</code></pre>
<pre class="samOption prettyprint" style="display: none;"><code>Sam</code></pre>
<pre class="admOption prettyprint" style="display: none;"><code>Admin</code></pre>
```

Adding your selectbox:

```
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
    <option value="jayOption">Jay</option>
    <option value="samOption">Sam</option>
    <option value="admOption">Admin</option>
</select>
```

we can toggle the `<pre>` elements with the following code:

```
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
    if(nameSelect.value){
        var preElements = document.getElementsByClassName('prettyprint');
        for(var i=0; i < preElements.length; i++){  
            //if the class contains the selected value, then show it, else hide it
            preElements[i].style.display = preElements[i].classList.contains(nameSelect.value)?'block':'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Making use of [`classList`](http://caniuse.com/classlist)

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X4LD5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide an element of a dropdown list like that.  Try setting it's "disabled" attribute instead.  Either that, or recreate the list dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I forked your jsfiddle to give an example of how you might acheive this using a naming convention on the divs like

```
<div id="admDivCheck0" style="display:none;">
```

corresponds to the value in

```
<option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7Rmh/ here is the fiddle :D

Comment: Thanks clancer this looks like it might do the trick though I can't say I'm sure exactly yet how it's working! I'll give it a go cheers.

Comment: @Ciarán sure, to explain a little first it selects all divs.. this will need to be made more specific if you want to use it inside another page. then all these divs are hidden with display="none" then we find the div with the id matching the value of nameSelect and display it